# How can I exit the 'loop' of 'top | grep user'?

Tags: linux

I want to use `top | grep user` to know how many processes are running.

However, after I run `top | grep user > temp_file`, the command just keeps running.

How can I safely stop it with information being written to the `temp_file`?

Comment: Use ps instead of top

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-n 1` option to `top` to make it only do one iteration.

Probably the better tool to use would be `ps`, as in `ps aux | grep user`.

Answer (score 0):

If count is all you're interested in:

```
pgrep -cu username
```